# What should I do about this gap between the tub and tile?

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout, tiling, tub

anyone have any ideas what to do with the front edge of the tub.  My tub is rounded on the front top edges.  I have about a half inch gap. Looks to small to cut and mortar in a triangular piece of tile.   I was thinking of using sanded grout against the tile and caulk abound the tub.  Any suggestions? I have colored sanded caulk from the tile shop.  Could I just fill the gap with this?  Suggestions welcome[image]

Comment: If you go from a tile layout with uniform grout joints and suddenly jump to a large grout joint, it won't look right.  Better to shape an odd piece of tile and have the joints look even.  A wet saw with a continuous diamond rim will let you grind close to the blade safely.

Comment: @HerrBag You're suggesting cutting a ~1/4" wide sliver of tile?

Comment: You could go to the effeort and make a skirting out of the tile that fits to the curve- maybe a different colour. Its allot of effort but will look the best. Easiest.... white silicone. Not grout because it crack with time and white because it will visually level out the bath.

Comment: @tester101 no, the photo wasn't up when I commented.  The correct course *would* have been to start the row lower and put the 'hook' on the lower right base row.

Comment: @ppumkin - the grout might crack and what with hitting it with some caulk if it cracks?

Comment: @HerrBag - The row is flush with the tub... but the tub is curved towards the end. What really should have been done is tiled "BEHIND" the tub!!  DMoore.. double work?

Comment: Just do what you said man. Sanded caulk is your best bet!

Answer (score 3):

OK this is a lot of talk about a very minor issue.

First the issue is because you laid your first row too high (or it's slightly off level).  I would also suggest going a little further out of the tub but if your tiles laid out to that width without cut I could see stopping.

Grout the gap.  Anything else would be silly at the point.  Also your grout color matches your tile well so should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently tiled my shower. What about laying something to serve as a spacer on top of the tub, something like 1/4" plywood (with masking tape on top). At the rounded top corner you'll have improvise more. Something like silly putty shaped to match the height of the plywood comes to mind, or layers of duct tape.  Then grout above it. When the grout dries, pull out the spacer material and fill with caulk. You'll have to decide whether this will look okay. Cutting a slice of tile to fit in there doesn't make sense to me though because you would need a grout line above and a caulk line below and that pretty much takes up the 1/2".

Got another idea from the additional posts: consider cutting out a stip at the bottom of the tiles coming down to the tub, say 4" (or whatever you think will work aesthetically) . Then cutting 3 1/2" pieces to fit in the empty spaces. That'l leave 1/4" for grout, and 1/4" for caulk. Alternately, you could knock out the tiles right above the tub, and cut two tiles that fit. Depends on the aesthetics to you. Not great ideas, but worth considering.